# How can i remake XPath locators to UIAutomation locators?

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

How can i remake XPath locators to UIAutomation locators?
Example this xpath locator:
    `//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[4]/UIAAlert[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAStaticText[2]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to remake xpath value to UIautomation, methods are as follows.

[!Calculator app example]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQr3J.png

Before going to these points FYI class name is taken as reference for xpath.

1. XPath using class and text attribute : 
   In above image you can see that button 5 has text attribute with value = 5 which is unique. Class name is android.widget.Button which is same for all number buttons. So we can create XPath using text attribute value with class name as bellow.
   xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='5']")
2. XPath using class and resource-id : 
   Here resource-id for button 5 is com.android.calculator2:id/digit5. Trailing part (e.g digit5, digit4, digit7) of resource-id is changing for every number buttons so we can use contains function to get relative XPath of button 5 as bellow.
   xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'digit5')]")

   - See more at: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html#sthash.08v6jFPe.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

You can get UIAutomator from Instrument.(Xcode - Automation tool)

please find the below UIAutomator for ur code,
**UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[3].alerts()[0].scrollViews()[0].staticTexts()[1]**

Note:
In Xpath index starts from 1.but in UIAutomator it starts from 0. Keep this in your mind.